# Is __init__ called every time for a subscriptable object that creates a dictionary dynamically?

Tags: python, performance, oop

I have this class, which is, of course, just a working example:

```
class Intervals(dict):
    def __init__(self, *_):
        self.update({'P5': 7})

class Intervals(metaclass=Intervals):
    pass
```

I like the idea, because I don't need an instance that way.

Just, is now, every time when I call `Intervals['P5']`, `__init__` run and a new dictionary built before a value can be returned?

Comment: Why are you using a meta class? And why do your classes share a name? What are you *actually trying to achieve?!* Surely you could have answered your own question with `print`, anyway?

Comment: Are you serious? Without the last two lines, `Intervals['P5']` would have to be `Intervals()['P5']`. That is also the reason why they both have the same name. Also, I just don't need an instance. But my question was whether that dictionary is built over and over again every time I want to retrieve a value. Because then, it wouldn't make sense to use a meta class or two classes having the same name...

Comment: Perfectly serious. The meta class doesn't have to have the same name as the class for this to work. And you still haven't explained *why* you're doing this; what is the requirement that has led to to this solution?

Comment: You have it wrong. A metaclass is supposed to yield a class when instantiated. Here, your metaclass yields a dict that cannot be instantiated. If you want to use syntaxes like `Intervals['P5']`, you should look into the [singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python).

Comment: But everything is obvious. I would like to have an object that is subscriptable and that I can use just like a dictionary without having an instance. The question is: Will a new dictionary be built every time I call `Intervals['P5']`?

Comment: The answer is no, because the last two lines of code are equivalent to `Intervals = Intervals()`.

Comment: That's quite nice, I guess, thanks. (My code looks good, everything makes sense, maybe it's a hack, but so far I haven't seen any flaws.)

Comment: *"I would like to have an object that is subscriptable and that I can use just like a dictionary without having an instance"* - so you really want to implement `__getitem__`/`__setitem__` on a class? You **still haven't said *why***. @Vincent is right, you are abusing the meta class, which should inherit from `type` and return a class. But my original point was that you could trivially answer your own question by adding e.g. `print('This is happening')` to `Instance.__init__`

Comment: I have also implemented `__call__`, `__contains__`, `__missing__`. And when `__getitem__` is called with a value the key is returned. But now that I see that `Intervals = Intervals()` is equivalent I am changing things  a bit anyway. As far as the print part is concerned you are absolutely right. Didn't get the point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a new dictionary is not built every time you call `Intervals['P5']`.

Actually, your code is equivalent to:

```
class Intervals(dict):
    def __init__(self, *_):
        self.update({'P5': 7})

Intervals = Intervals()
```

You simply create an `Intervals` object (that is just a `dict` initialized with some values), and store it in a variable called `Intervals`, shadowing the `Intervals` class.